# socket.io impact on server performance

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My app is hosted on heroku as a REST api on top of node.js server.
I want to add socket.io to it to be able to send events to users.

Lets say 500 000 users will use my app at the same time - so 500 000 users connected to socket.io in parallel.

1. How this will impact server performance?
2. How much more requests/sec this will cause on my server?

Comment: it will cause a short lag on socket.io processing, 500.000 users is considered a high number and probably it will make use of alot of ram. So i would considered dedicated hosting for this kind of task.

Comment: Let's say I will host socket.io server separately - on heroku for example. What do you think - it will better scale horizontally or vertically?